# How do I install Cairo binaries for Python

Tags: python, binary, installation, cairo

I am trying to install Cairo for Python 2.7 in windows.  I have installed igraph. There are binaries for this system on Christoph's site.  I have downloaded the appropriate binary.  How do I use pip to install the Cairo binary.

Comment: If you have a Windows binary, just run it. It should act as its own installer.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on it and figured it out.  Here are detailed instructions.  They will work (with appropriate modifications for any binary Python package:

Installing Cairo in Python for Windows.

1. Go to  site https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, Chrisoph Gohlke’s site
2. Download the appropriate version of Cairo to your Download folder
3. Move the downloaded file from the Download folder to  c:\Pythonxx\Scripts (xx is the version of Python)
4. Open a command window.  Not the Python command window.
5. Enter cd c:\Pythonxx\Scripts.  The system will give you a command line in that directory
6. Enter:
      pip install  downloaded-file-name, 
   for example pycairo-1.10.0-cp27-none-win32.whl