# Django - - OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 -- Continues to Appear Even After Downloading GTK+ Bundle 3.10.4

Tags: python, django

After installing WeasyPrint, I am getting this error: "Error in Django: OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2"

Here are all the details:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0420DE40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\myshop\myshop\urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    url(r'^orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\myshop\orders\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\myshop\orders\views.py", line 7, in <module>
    import weasyprint
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 375, in <module>
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import computed_values
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\computed_values.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\text.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2')
  File "C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 38, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2
```

I have found a solution to a similar problem here on Stackoverflow: [Getting "OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556368/getting-oserror-dlopen-failed-to-load-a-library-cairo-cairo-2-on-windows#). As suggested there, I downloaded one of the packages, called GTK+ Bundle 3.10.4, from http://win32builder.gnome.org/. I followed the instructions mentioned there. But still, the error appears.

I also found another potential solution here: [dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437041/dlopen-failed-to-load-a-library-cairo-cairo-2)

I have installed Choco in my PC and ran the following commands in the Command Prompt.

```
choco install libcairo2
```

Now, I get these errors:

```
Chocolatey v0.10.8
Installing the following packages:
libcairo2
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
libcairo2 not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
 Version: ""
 Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"
```

**I am completely stuck. Please, help me. I am doing a Django course on building an online shop. I can't proceed unless I fix the issue. So, I am badly in need of help.**

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28287170/2426) works for me. Maybe you should try it.